# How to scale Network Bandwidth for media server?

Tags: networking, load-balancing, bandwidth

We are running a WebRTC Server to facilitate audio/video call feature on our app. But as our concurrent users keeps on increasing, we are facing network bandwidth issue.

Max cap on google cloud vm instance is **32Gbps** but there is also a limit of 2Gbps per core and it is throttling our performance. What I want to know is, if there is a way to scale network bandwidth? As mentioned in **Dicord's** [article](https://blog.discord.com/how-discord-handles-two-and-half-million-concurrent-voice-users-using-webrtc-ce01c3187429), they are able to scale to **220Gbps**.

Things I have tried:

1. **Nginx server** :- It only redistributes the traffic but it does not scale the network bandwidth

Things I think I can do:

1. **DNS Load balancing** :- This is what I found when researching for how does CDN like networks work.
2. Make a **separate API** that returns the IP address to make connection to for the new call. Basically, do what DNS server is doing via my API server.

What I want to know much better is evaluate different options so as to make a better choice. Is there any other option that I am missing over here?